# PHP preg_replace replacing newlines, but nothing works

Tags: php, regex

I have a text field retrieved by a Solr query that contains the body of an email. I am trying to replace embedded line breaks with paragraph tags via PHP like so:

```
$text = $item->Body[0];
$new_line = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
preg_replace($new_line, '</p><p>', $text);
echo $text;
```

When I show the result in my IDE/debugger the newline characters are not replaced and are still there:

[image: Output example]

I have been going through threads on this site trying patterns suggested by different people including "/\s+/" and PHP_EOL and "/(\r\n|\r|\n)/" and nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can just use `str_replace($new_line, '<\p><p>', $text);`

Comment: [`$text = str_replace($new_line,'</p><p>',$text);`](http://ideone.com/M88OZu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the delimiter around your regex strings and you are not assigning the value.
You can also reduce your regex:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\r?\n|\r/", '</p><p>', $text);
```

You might want switch to the multibyte safe version. They work with Unicode and you don't need delimiters there ;)

```
$text = mb_ereg_replace("\r?\n|\r", '</p><p>', $text);
```

Comment: Well there's that too :-/

Comment: You don't have to take care about multibyte characters! `\r` and `\n` are in the ascii range whatever the encoding. Other thing, with `preg` functions, you can use the `\R` alias that matches any newline sequence.

Comment: I was not thinking about a unicode pattern but a unicode `$text`. I didn't know about `\R`. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't matter in this specific case. I just wanted to add a hint that these functions exist.

Comment: In this case, for utf-8 encoding strings, you can also add the u modifier with `preg` functions.

Comment: i was aware of mb_ but didn't know about mb_ereg_replace. Perfect for frenchies like me that need some accents to make user happy.

Answer (score 4):

`preg_replace` is for regular expressions. You want a simple string replacement, so you should use `str_replace`:

```
$text = $item->Body[0];
$new_line = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$text = str_replace($new_line, '</p><p>', $text);
echo $text;
```